# What does “No more variables left in this MIB View” mean (Linux)?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to run this command:

```
 snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost netSnmpPlaypen.7375
```

which gives the following output:

```
NET-SNMP-MIB::netSnmpPlaypen.7375 = No more variables left in this MIB View
```

can anyone help me how to come up with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that this is a site about programming problems. Please try to ask your question at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690216/what-does-no-more-variables-left-in-this-mib-view-mean-linux